# Request.post() method without waiting for response

Tags: python, post, python-requests

i want to send this request but without waiting for a response:

```
requests.post(url=agregar, data=data, allow_redirects=False , headers=user_agent)
```

how i do it ?

Comment: You can use a thread.

Comment: you can use threading

Answer (score 0):

You can make Asynchronous Method with async and await
read about Asynchronous and Task I hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

You can use Threading.Thread class in python. https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread

Comment: Abhishek, a link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33774277)